# Tube geometry not working with array of vertices [ THREE.js ]

Tags: javascript, arrays, three.js, geometry, vertices

I am having a little problem creating a tube spline from a array random points. I don´t have no clue why this doesn't work.

I get this error:

Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'x' of undefined

```
    for (var i = 0; i < 5; i++) {

                    //particle = new THREE.Sprite( material );
                    particle.position.x = (Math.random() - 0.5)* 20;
                    particle.position.y = (Math.random() - 0.5)* 20;
                    particle.position.z = (Math.random() - 0.5)* 20;

                    particle.scale.x = particle.scale.y = 1;
                    scene.add( particle );

                    geometry.vertices.push( particle.position );

                    //var line = new THREE.Line( geometry, new THREE.LineBasicMaterial( { color: 0xffffff, opacity: 0.5 } ) );

                    //scene.add( line );

//HERE IS WHERE THE PROBLEM START

        var tubeVertices = new THREE.Vector3(geometry.vertices);
        var Spline = new THREE.CatmullRomCurve3( 
                  tubeVertices
                 );

        var material = new THREE.MeshLambertMaterial( { color: 0xff00ff } );
        var tubeGeometry = new THREE.TubeGeometry( Spline, 5, 1, 5);
        var tube = new THREE.Mesh(tubeGeometry,material);
        scene.add( tube );   

       }
```

I had tried this way but it doesn't work also. I add a picture of the error.

```
    ....
    var tubeVertices = new THREE.Vector3(geometry.vertices[1]);
    console.log(tubeVertices);

     var sampleClosedSpline = new THREE.CatmullRomCurve3( 
                new THREE.Vector3(geometry.vertices[0]),
                new THREE.Vector3(geometry.vertices[1]),
                new THREE.Vector3(geometry.vertices[2]),
                new THREE.Vector3(geometry.vertices[3]),
                new THREE.Vector3(geometry.vertices[4])
             );
   ...
```

[here is what i am trying to make](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ACjFP.jpg)
[ERROR_IMG](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ptwqg.png)

Thank you in advance

Comment: Could you explain this `var tubeVertices = new THREE.Vector3(geometry.vertices);` and this `new THREE.Vector3(geometry.vertices[0])`?

Comment: what i am trying to do. is getting the vertices position of the particles (particle.position), and make it as the vertices of the tube geometry. it is impossible that way?

Comment: Just out of curiousity, why do you use the outdated revision of three.js (r73)?

Comment: Because i was having problems with the StereoEffect.js. it was getting some kind of error with the last version. and this one seems to work. Do you know how can i make the particle position to the vectors of the tubegeometry? or any work around?

Comment: Could you illustrate your question with a picture? As I still can't get what you want to achieve.

Comment: i added a image to the main post. sorry if the question is not so well explained